# Manipulate DOM elements in background.html, Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to manipulate DOM elements in the background. What I want to, is to have a YouTube player in the background.html file, which can be manipulated in the popup.html file. However, I'm stuck on how to actually manipulate elements in the background.

**background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bogus</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="youtubeContainer" height="480" width="480"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems as though, if you want to interact with your background page, you're dealing with a call to chrome.extensions.getBackgroundPage(). However, I'm quite unsure on how to access the DOM once the backgroundPage has been accessed. Hope someone can help!

Comment: so your main page is background.html, and inside it, youre loading a page through iframe called popup,html,  you want to manipulate the DOM inside your popup.html, correct?

Comment: My main page is popup.html, which has controls that fire events to popup.js. In popup.js I want to change the content in the YouTube player based on what was clicked in popup.html. The YouTube player lives in background.html. Hope this clears things up.